# Creating a project using craftcms

Tags: xampp

When I run,
composer create-project craftcms/craft .
command following error occurs:

```
Creating a "craftcms/craft" project at "./"
Installing craftcms/craft (2.0.10)
```

- Installing craftcms/craft (2.0.10): Extracting archive
  Created project in C:\Users\Abhishek Shukla\craftycoffee-2024.
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- craftcms/cms[4.4.0, ..., 4.5.14] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
- Root composer.json requires craftcms/cms ^4.4.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[4.4.0, ..., 4.5.14].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

I tried to firstly, i open the xampp and then again run this command.